# Visual Studio 2010 - "Find All" button disabled when trying to to Find in Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Any idea?

Visual Studio 2010 - "Find All" button disabled when trying to do "Find In Files

Comment: I found the reason... weird Visual Studio 2010 behaviour. 

Open any CODE file and try doing CTRL+SHIFT+F, now are you allowed to search all files in vs2010.


Refer to link below for more information.
 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622037/find-all-button-on-find-in-files-window-disabled-until-code-window-is-opened

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

As it says in the comment posted by the author of the question, this is a known issue (at least known to Microsoft) of VS2010. Since the [bug report page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622037/find-all-button-on-find-in-files-window-disabled-until-code-window-is-opened#details) is a lot more confusing than Stack Overflow, I'll quote the work around suggested by the Microsoft dev that closed the issue, which doesn't involve opening any file (emphasis mine).

> If you type text into the "Find What" text box and select "Entire Solution" from the "Look In" dropdown menu (**even though it is already selected**) the Find All button becomes enabled.

I should also add that the issue was closed as "Won't Fix".

Comment: At this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/find-all-button-gets-disabled-in-find-and-replace/732396 they claimed to be working on an improved dialog (back in 2019). VS gets more and more buggy.